# Make sacct to not truncate the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

Tags: slurm, sacct

I need to find the taskID of my job array that got a timeout. So I use sacct as follows.

```
sacct -u <UserID> -j <jobID> -s TIMEOUT
```

and I get this as output.

```
User     JobID        start
----     -----        -----
<UserID> <JobID>_90+  ....
```

My taskID is a four-digit number that has been truncated by sacct and displayed as 90+ instead. How can I get the full taskID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sacct` command has a `--format` parameter that allows customising the columns shown, along with their size.

The following will show the same three columns as your example, with a 30-character wide column for jobid:

```
sacct -u <UserID> -j <jobID> -s TIMEOUT --format user,jobid%-30,start
```